# Как "нажать" на кнопку через requests в python на сайте funpay.com

Tags: python, requests

Что бы поднять предложения на сайте, нужно нажимать на кнопку. Как это можно сделать через запрос?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если при нажатии на кнопку загружается другая страница, или хотя бы url меняется, то можно сразу загружать эту url. А иначе никак. Только использовать для этого библиотеку selenium

Answer (score 0):

Post запрос на этот url с data которая указана у тебя на скрине. Там указывает id игры и id услуги